# ng-bootstrap typeahead not filtering out none matching results

Tags: api, angular5, typeahead, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am having some trouble implementing the ng-boostrap typeahead.
Everything works except the filtering. It bolds the matching text, but problem is that it doesn't filter out the non-matching results.

I have used the wikipedia sample.

component.html

```
<input id="typeahead-http" type="text" [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultFormatter]="formatter" [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
```

component.ts

```
search = (text$: Observable<any>) =>
    text$
    .debounceTime(300)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(() => this.searching = true)
    .switchMap(term =>
    this._genreService.search(term)
        .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
        .catch(() => {
        this.searchFailed = true;
        return of([]);
        }))
    .do(() => this.searching = false)
    .merge(this.hideSearchingWhenUnsubscribed)

    formatter = (x: {name: string}) => x.name;
```

service.ts

```
public search(str): Observable<any> {
    return this._dataService.getAll(`${this._baseApiUrl}/lists/genre`);
}
```